# Error loadig dataset with read_csv command

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu

I'm trying to read a 3.6GB (3559267227 bytes) csv file with this command:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataAnalysis/data/featureEngineering/weather_VCI_data_with_skyc1_reindex.csv")
```

In the terminal I get the "Killed" word when I am trying to run it.
I think it might be a memory problem and that's why I ran this command.

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 62927
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 8192
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 62927
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

What should I change and how, to be able to load the data set?

Comment: Please provide the full error stack. I suggest you have a look at chunks to read a dataset in smaller pieces

Comment: What also did you test? Take ideas from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25962114/842935

Comment: How can I provide the full error stack? If I use the same command and data set on Windows I don't get an error, so it's related to Linux.

Comment: What size is your `weather_VCI_data_with_skyc1_reindex.csv` file?

Comment: The size of the  weather_VCI_data_with_skyc1_reindex.csv file is 3.6GB (3559267227 bytes) .